# A Model Structure on Symmetric Monoidal Categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, ct.category-theory, stable-homotopy

The recent article found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3622) revisits Thomason's proof that symmetric monoidal categories model all connective spectra, but stops short of showing that there is a full closed model structure on this category (as does, it seems, Thomason's original paper.)  Is there such a thing?

My guess is some lifting similar to how the model structure on small categories is derived would work, but I'm not sure if there are any complications.

Comment: Elmendorf's conjecture below has a corresponding result in terms of dendroidal sets which is proved here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6891

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One basic problem is that the category of symmetric monoidal categories isn't complete.  Its completion, in a basic sense, is the category of multicategories, on which it seems reasonable to conjecture there is a model category structure whose homotopy category "is" the connective part of stable homotopy -- we hope to prove this soon.  See Elmendorf and Mandell, "Permutative categories, multicategories, and algebraic K-theory", which just appeared in Algebraic and Geometric Topology.

Comment: Yes, shortly after writing this it had occurred to me that I wasn't sure if the the category had all the required limits and colimits and this might be an obstruction.  The idea of using multicategories is intriguing.  I'll be sure to have a look at your paper.

Comment: What's the state of this work in progress? Isn't the category of multicategories just the category of (non-symmetric) colored operads? Does the recent work of Marcy Robertson get the required model structure?